# Select only first object in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Basically I want to adapt this code for LINQ:

```
private Tile CheckCollision(Tile[] tiles)
{
    foreach (var tile in tiles)
    {
        if (tile.Rectangle.IntersectsWith(Rectangle))
        {
            return tile;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The code checks each tile and returns the first tile that collides with the object. I only want the *first* tile, not an array of tiles like I would get if I use this:

```
private Tile CheckCollision(Tile[] tiles)
{
    var rtn = 
        from tile in tiles
        where tile.Rectangle.IntersectsWith(Rectangle)
        select tile;

}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` extension method that allows you to retrieve the first element matching a certain condition:

```
private Tile CheckCollision(Tile[] tiles)
{
    return tiles.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Rectangle.IntersectsWith(Rectangle));
}
```

The `.First()` extension method will throw an exception if no element is found in the array that matches the required condition. The `.FirstOrDefault()` on the other hand will silently return null. So use the one that better suits your needs.

Notice that there's also the `.Single()` extension method that you could use. The difference with `.First()` is that `.Single()` will throw an exception if more than one elements matches the condition whereas `.First()` will return the first one.